# How can we change value openSearcher=true from JAVA Code?

Tags: solr

I am trying to insert data to SOLR using HardCommit. By default value of openSearcher=false in solrConfig.xml. I want to change openSearcher=true through JAVA code. Donot want to  make change to SOLR.config.xml. Is there any way to do that??

Thanks

Comment: _How_ are you committing data today?

Comment: Using SolrTemplate.commit in JAVA and openSearcher=false in SOLRConfig.xml. But i want to change openSearcher=true from my JAVA Code not from XML file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with [Config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/config-api.html). You could check current configuration by firing GET request at /config endpoint. E.g

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection-name/config
```

and set some property with command like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection-name/config 
    -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d 
'{
  "set-property": {
    "updateHandler.autoCommit.openSearcher": true
  }
}'
```

This could be of course done in Java code, by using some popular HTTP client or by firing your implementation of abstract `SolrRequest` in **SolrJ**